# Div margin always off the right side of the page

Tags: html, css

I'm a coding a simple navbar component with 100% width and a margin, but no matter what I try it always seems to be way off the page on the right side of the screen. Any idea where the problem could come from?

I've tried to simplify things by creating a simple box within a div and giving it 16px margins, but I have the same problem. I was thinking maybe my CSS inherits from conflicting property of the body but after checking the inspector that doesn't seem to be the case.

Thanks for any insights!

```css
//_navbar.scss

.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    margin: 16px;
}
```

```html
// _navbar.html.erb

  <div class="box">
    Hello?
  </div>
```

Comment: Your CSS must be inheriting something from somewhere.

Comment: did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606889/div-to-the-right-side-of-the-page , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740166/how-to-prevent-div-from-getting-cut-of-when-resizing-window

Comment: What browser are you testing in would be useful as well not all browsers are the same (or even compliant *I'm looking at you IE*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding this **body** property to CSS you disable the automatic 8px margin that the body tag has. 
Try this new CSS stylesheet.

```
.box {
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    margin: 16px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}


body {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: thank you! Adding right and left with 0px seemed to fix my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Because `width: 100%` **PLUS** `margin: 16px` is more than 100%.

Maybe you want to apply the `margin` to the body or whatever container is the parent of `.box`?